# How do I call delete operator from an outer function in C++?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

If I have something like that:

```
char* plainText = init();
delete [] plainText;
```

All is working normal and the dynamic memory is marked as free.

But when I call something like this:

```
char* plainText = init();
deletePlainText(plainText);
```

Where

```
void deletePlainText(char *plainText)
{
   delete[] plainText;
}
```

The memory is not marked as free it is something like that:

```
+  plainText 0x005cb160 "îþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþ... char *
```

Is it possible to call delete operator from outer function and how?

Original Source:

```
http://pastebin.com/1pybC02t
http://pastebin.com/KbtfG5Cw
http://pastebin.com/NSyULHaF
```

Comment: What makes you think that the memory is not marked as deleted. The memory is not overwritten with `0` or any other value when freed. Only the control structure marks it as free.

Comment: Because when I use direct method (without calling outer function) the debug watch variable shows:

-  plainText 0x00008123 <Error reading characters of string.> char *

Comment: I observe it with watching the plainText as variable.
In the first case plainText is:

plainText 0x00008123 <Error reading characters of string.> char *

Comment: I'm with @RedX. Memory deleted typically does not show in any way special in the memory dump.... There are implementations of memory allocators that mark deleted memory with some special pattern (mainly for debugging purposes), for example [libumem](https://blogs.oracle.com/jwadams/entry/debugging_with_libumem_and_mdb) in Solaris... but the otherwise, the old content being there is just by chance that the memory has not been put to a different use.

Comment: That sounds like a issue with the debug watch.  The pointer was freed in the scope of the deletePlainText function, and the watcher doesn't recognize that as affecting the calling scope.  Do you have visibility on which regions are actually allocated?

Comment: If you want deleted memory to contain a specific pattern, then write the pattern before deleting the memory.

Comment: Thomas -> I do not want to include some specific patter - I just want to be assured it is deleted (marked as free). In this case the pointer is still alive and as you can see the strange pattern is repeating infinitely, which means the debugger didn't recognize its length.

Comment: Joe, sorry for the delay. I did this:

0030F988
0035B160
0035B161
0035B162

On 

cout << &plainText << endl;
 cout << (void *) &plainText[0] << endl;
 cout << (void *) &plainText[1] << endl;
 cout << (void *) &plainText[2] << endl;

Comment: Let's get specific. Which OS, compiler and debugger are you using? Your watchpoints are on which variables and lines?

Comment: RedX --> Windows 7 64 bit, Visual Studio 2012, I watch plainText only, which is a pointer to array of chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see into the memory window in VS (address of variavle 'plainText'),it looks as follows:

0x0056BB28  ee fe ee fe ee fe ee fe ee fe ee fe ee fe fe   îþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþ

This is the information from : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29

> FEEEFEEE  "Fee fee", Used by Microsoft's debug HeapFree() to mark
>   freed heap memory. Some nearby internal bookkeeping values may have
>   the high word set to FEEE as well.

So this indicates that your memory has been freed and now you should not use it.This magic number is Microsoft specific memory manager behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already solved this and there is much sense in this. Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the issue. I still believe the program is not behaving normally (for example - why such pattern doesn't appear when I delete the function from the inner block of main - without using outer function)?

Further more - to prove my point of view:

Let's define outer function:

void deleteCodedText(int * codedText)
{
 delete[] codedText;
}

And let's put in main this:

int * codedArray = EncodingPlainText(plainText,charTable);
deleteCodedText(codedArray);

Code Blows!

Comment: @user3485143: It would be really nice if you post your code, which is creating problem. The behavior can not be the different and we would get the same thing. You have also mentioned that Code Blows!, which may indicates that your program is corrupting the memory or you are freeing the memory. I would suggest you to put your code in your original question.

Comment: I have just uploaded the code (3 separate files). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Error found (line 65 EncodingDecodingTask.cpp) Thank you!